# How to parse DbGeometry object into List<T>?

Tags: c#, sql-server, geospatial

I'm trying to parse a polygon, which is presented as `DbGeometry` class (from the `System.Data.Entity.Spatial`) to some List representation, but there were fails.

I've tried:
 - to convert it with the method .ToList<>()
 - to parse using JSON library in .NET, but have sample code from different websites failed with deserializing `DbGeometry`

So, right now I'm returning geometry as a string in my Web API application:

[image]

If I couldn't find any solution how, to represent it as list of doubles I will have to parse manually it in JavaScript, which way I think is very incorrect and there must be some solution.

I'm using Entity Framework v.6.1.1, which has prepared the next model:

```
public partial class Buildings
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> has_holes { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry polygon_data { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry position_wgs { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry position_mercator { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> height { get; set; }
    public string street_name { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry holes_data { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> angle { get; set; }
}
```

I've shown it, if you want to see a structure of the table from `MSSQL CE` (which is an embedded db, or `LocalDb`, another name).

So I want:

- System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry polygon_data
- System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry holes_data

Be prepared as lists of doubles, so my question is: `How can I parse DbGeometry instance, which holds a collection of points into List<Point>?`.

Comment: `How can I parse DbGeometry instance, which holds a collection of points into List<double>?`well you really shouldn't as a the `DbGeometry` can hold a point, up to a `List<List<Point>>()`.  So what are you going to do if it one of those and you only want a `List<Double>` (which doesn't really even make sense)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm going to build a building in 3D using three.js, also I can say I've already done it, but using old WebForms of ASP.NET and MySQL, right now I've developed new Web API (v2), which provides me an API like *.ashx web handlers were providing (but they weren't RESTful, it's one of the options why I have decided to move into Web API) and have prepared data in mssql ce (localDb). So I'm going to port already working application from one backend to another.

Comment: Nothing in your comment answers my question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I need only a plain list of points and a separate lists of possible holes. As for the base model of building. It's always presented as polygon, as for the 3D development part, I've just needed a single list with doubles for building it in WebGL context (triangulating process). If buildings has holes, each hole is defining as polygon. So, List<List<Point>>, could be presented so, but I see this as List<Point[]>. Did I answer your question? If no, please say it again, but maybe in some other form.

Comment: `I need only a plain list of points.` well a `List<Double>` is not a list of points.  Maybe you meant to ask that as the question?

Comment: @ErikPhilips No, thanks for admitting this. Of course I need List<Point>, where point is a `class Point { public double X; public double Y; }`, and as for the holes a collection of lists of points, because, there could be 2 or 3 (and else) holes in building.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem. What I did was, created extension method that parse the given geometry data to points. @Erik Philips also have nice solution though. This is what I came up with.

```
public static class ExtensionString
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static ExtensionString()
    {
        _replacements["LINESTRING"] = "";
        _replacements["CIRCLE"] = "";
        _replacements["POLYGON"] = "";
        _replacements["POINT"] = "";
        _replacements["("] = "";
        _replacements[")"] = "";
    }

    public static List<Point> ParseGeometryData(this string s)
    {
        var points = new List<Point>();

        foreach (string to_replace in _replacements.Keys)
        {
            s = s.Replace(to_replace, _replacements[to_replace]);
        }

        string[] pointsArray = s.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            double[] coordinates = new double[2];

            //gets x and y coordinates split by space, trims whitespace at pos 0, converts to double array
            coordinates = Array.ConvertAll(pointsArray[i].Remove(0, 1).Split(null), double.Parse);

            points.Add(new Point() { X = coordinates[0], Y = coordinates[1] });
        }

        return points;
    }
}
```

And just use it like this

```
List<System.Drawing.Point> points = geometryDataStr.ParseGeometryData();
```

Comment: Good approach, The point is not always double, only in System.Windows (For example the Drawing library uses int to describe the point). But if you cant access System.Windows you can create your own class. Thanks for sharing your code.

Answer (score 2):

If your Geometry is Valid then you can do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbGeometry test = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON((1 1, 1 2, 3 3, 1 1))");

        var foo = test.AsText();
        var points = new List<Point>();

        Console.WriteLine(foo);
        if (foo.StartsWith("POLYGON ((")
            && foo.EndsWith("))"))
        {
            foo = foo.Substring(10, foo.Length - 12);
            var rawPoints = foo.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            foreach (var rawPoint in rawPoints)
            {
                var splitPoint = rawPoint.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                points.Add(new Point() { X = decimal.Parse(splitPoint[1]), Y = decimal.Parse(splitPoint[0]) });
            }
        }

        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(point.ToString());
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Point
{
    public decimal X { get; set; }
    public decimal Y { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[X={0}],[Y={1}]", X, Y);
    }
}
```

result:

```
POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 3 3, 1 1))
[X=1],[Y=1]
[X=2],[Y=1]
[X=3],[Y=3]
[X=1],[Y=1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm a little stunned that there isn't a strongly typed solution. It seems odd to me that the DbGeometry type doesn't provide a property for this.

Comment: Considering the DbGeometry holds [POINT(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933979.aspx), [LINE(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933976.aspx), [POLYGON(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933971.aspx), [Multi-POINT(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933997.aspx), [Multi-LINE(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933883.aspx), [Multi-POLYGONs(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933816.aspx) and [GeometryCollection(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933919.aspx), it would be difficult.